# Azure storage account missing from new azure portal but still on old azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I'm having a bottle neck problem with an azure cloud service. The service used to work fine and basically what it does, is to storage information from an azure storage account into an azure data base. The last month no data was loaded into the azure db, the service has not been changed in a while, the database does not have lock problems but when i tried to check my storage account it turns that is not available in the new azure portal but in the old portal, from the old portal i don't have the same options as the new portal. The metrics are ok, but this bottle neck problem I'm having whit the data load could be related to the missing storage account in the new portal? it could be some azure migration problem? Please any idea how to figure out what is going on..... thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The new portal has two areas for storage, including 'Classic' storage accounts for accounts created using the legacy API / tools / portal.

On the menu, you'll see both `Storage accounts` and `Storage accounts (classic)` (same thing with virtual machines):

[image: menu]

If you pin both to your dashboard, you'll see two separate lists of storage accounts:

[image: storage on the dashboard]